# Find a pattern and replace

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is the input to my file.

```
Number : 123
PID    : IIT/123/Dakota
```

The expected output is :

```
Number : 111
PID    : IIT/111/Dakota
```

I want to replace 123 to 111. To solve this I have tried following:

```
awk '/Number/{$NF=111} 1' log.txt
awk -F '[/]' '/PID/{$2="123"} 1' log.txt
```

Comment: Please always use CODE TAGS `{}` button to wrap your sample input, sample output and your effort(s) code in it, so that it will be better understandable for us, like I edited your post, cheers.

Comment: wouldn't the simple `sed` command had worked??,like : `sed -i 's/123/111/g' file_name`  , because as per the question, OP only wants to replace `123` with `111` in the input_file.

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed 's/\b123\b/111/g' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** Or you want to substitute each line's `123` with `111` without checking any condition which you tried in your `awk` then simply do:

```
awk '{sub(/123/,"111")} 1'  Input_file
```

Change `sub` to `gsub` in case of many occurrences of `123` in a single line too.

***Explanation of above code:***

```
awk -v new_value="111" '  ##Creating an awk variable named new_value where OP could keep its new value which OP needs to be there in line.
/^Number/  {  $NF=new_value  } ##Checking if a line starts from Number string and then setting last field value to new_value variable here.
/^PID/     {  num=split($NF,array,"/"); ##Checking if a line starts from PID then creating an array named array whose delimiter it / from last field value
              array[2]=new_value; ##Setting second item of array to variable new_value here.
              for(i=1;i<=num;i++){  val=val?val "/" array[i]:array[i]  }; ##Starting a loop from 1 to till length of array and creating variable val to re-create last field of current line.
              $NF=val;    ##Setting last field value to variable val here.
              val=""      ##Nullifying variable val here.
           }
1' Input_file             ##Mentioning 1 to print the line and mentioning Input_file name here too.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** In case you need to `/` in your output too then use following `awk`.

```
awk -v new_value="111" '
/^Number/  {  $NF=new_value  }
/^PID/     {  num=split($NF,array,"/");
              array[2]=new_value;
              for(i=1;i<=num;i++){  val=val?val "/" array[i]:array[i]  };
              $NF=val;
              val=""
           }
1'   Input_file
```

---

Following `awk` may help you here.(Seems after I have applied code tags to your samples your sample input is changed a bit so editing my code accordingly now)

```
awk -F"[ /]" -v new_value="111" '/^Number/{$NF=new_value} /^PID/{$(NF-1)=new_value}1' Input_file
```

In case you want to save changes into Input_file itself append `> temp_file  &7 mv temp_file  Input_file` in above code then.

***Explanation:***

```
awk -F"[ /]" -v new_value="111" ' ##Setting field separator as space and / to each line and creating awk variable new_value which OP wants to have new value.
/^Number/{   $NF=new_value      } ##Checking condition if a line is starting with string Number then change its last field to new_value value.
/^PID/   {   $(NF-1)=new_value  } ##Checking condition if a line starts from string PID then setting second last field to variable new_value.
1                                 ##awk works on method of condition then action, so putting 1 making condition TRUE here and not mentioning any action so by default print of current line will happen.
' Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please mention the reason for down vote?

Comment: No sir, it is not working . I want to replace the number with 111 . It's not happening

Comment: I am getting but the output is somewhat like this :      PID    : IIT 111 Dakota . The / is removed from it

Comment: Yeah sample input is exactly same as real one . But in the output i.e after awking , '/' is removed and replaced with a space

Comment: @KaverappaKU, done please check now, also you could remove not needed comments here to make post clear, cheers.

Comment: num=split($NF,array,"/");
              array[2]=new_value;
              for(i=1;i<=num;i++){  val=val?val "/" array[i]:array[i]  };
              $NF=val;
              val="" . Can i get explaination for this

Comment: @KaverappaKU, I believe explanation is already added in my code(s), you could go through `man awk` too for getting more details about `awk` functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use sed for something this simple ?

Print the change to the screen (test with this) :

```
  sed -e 's:123:111:g' f2.txt
```

Update the file (with this) :

```
  sed -i 's:123:111:g' f2.txt
```

Example:

```
$ sed -i 's:123:111:g' f2.txt 
$ cat f2.txt 
Number : 111
PID    : IIT/111/Dakota
```